# How do I receive mixed params in Spring MVC from AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring

I need to pass a json object and a string as parameters to my Java controller.

Here is what I am trying but getting `url = ""` in the controller.

1. Why is that?
2. How to achieve this?

```js
$scope.executeRequest = function(){
    var url = "http://"+$scope.data.serverIP+":"+$scope.data.serverPort;
    $http.post('/admin/executeRequest/',JSON.parse($scope.data.request),url).success(function(data){
        $scope.data.response = data;
    }).error( function ( data, status ) {
        $log.info("getting request object for api from server : failure");
        if ( status === 403 ) {
            $scope.show403( data );
        }
    });
};
```

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/executeRequest/",method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ProductCategoryResponse executeRequest(@RequestBody ProductCategoryRequest request, String url){
```

Comment: correction : i am not getting "" but null in url

Comment: I would make 2 steps here. Check net tab in firebug, when post. There you can see request and some more info, to understand UI part works. And second, try to make simple request form without Angular, to ensure Spring part works right.

Answer (score 0):

Append URL to the URL params and send $scope.data.request in the request body.

```
    $scope.executeRequest = function(){
        var url = "http://"+$scope.data.serverIP+":"+$scope.data.serverPort;
        $http.post('/admin/executeRequest?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url), $scope.data.request).success(function(data){
            $scope.data.response = data;
        }).error( function ( data, status ) {
            $log.info("getting request object for api from server : failure");
            if ( status === 403 ) {
                $scope.show403( data );
            }
        });
    };
```

Then change your java controller like this.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/executeRequest/",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ProductCategoryResponse executeRequest(@RequestBody ProductCategoryRequest request, @RequestParam String url){
```

Please see the Spring docs for @RequestParam for details.

Comment: i don't wish to go this way.....i have so many different objects that can be in request object(apart from ProductCatReq)....this way i'd have to make a new POJO for each one or else create an interface.....don't want to do that.

Comment: can i send one json object with {req,url} and extract them as request parameters somehow in the controller (does spring provide some annotations for that?)

Comment: no, spring does not support this and there is no annotations for that. You can send the original request model object in the request body as json and other data as url query params. Then you can get the json with RequestBody annotation and get data from url query params with Requestparam annotation. In this way you can get multiple data in the controller parameters

Comment: or can you post that code as answer. i will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/admin/executeRequest_parentcategories", "/admin/executeRequest_subcategories"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ProductCategoryResponse executeProductCategoryRequest(@RequestParam(value = "url") String url,
        @RequestParam(value = "api") String api, @RequestBody ProductCategoryRequest request) {
```

and the http call for this like :

```
        var url = '/admin/executeRequest_parentcategories+'?url=http://'+$scope.data.serverIP+":"+$scope.data.serverPort+"&api="+$scope.data.apiSelected;
    $http.post(url,JSON.parse($scope.data.request)).success(function(data){
```

thanks sohan for the help :)